# How to fill in HTML file contents with some data C#

Tags: c#

I am working with Windows Form Application.

I need to fill in HTML file contents with some data e.g. user name. How I can do this.

I know I can use for example

```
string x = string.format("<HTML><BODY><P>{0}</P></BODY></HTML>",textbox1.text);
```

But I want to fill in contents in HTML file, which already exist and replace some of its tags. 
e.g. <%username%>

Comment: Why not load the file and do a string.Replace?

Comment: ya its a good idea, I didn't thought of it. How can I load it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like?

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(myFileName);
fileContents = fileContents.Replace("<%username%>", textbox1.Text);
File.WriteAllText(fileContents, myFileName);
```

Comment: If I need to fill HTML file 20K times. Don't you think it will slowdown the process. Actually I will first replace the contents of HTML file and then send this as an email. If there are 20K email then 20K times the whole file contents will be saved in string and then replace with some data.

Comment: @Kami don't you think we know nothing about number of times you want to fill file